# How can I have 4 videos as 1 using gstreamer, with 1 large to the left and 3 smaller to the right (these should have 1 above the other)?

Tags: gstreamer

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I've been trying with the videobox plugin but all I'm getting is 4 equally sized boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously did something similar to what you described using 3 cameras.

Here's the pipe I used for it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=800,  height=480,  framerate=25/1 ! alpha alpha=1.0 ! videobox left=-800 ! videomixer name=mix sink_00::xpos=0 sink_01::xpos=800 sink_02::xpos=0 sink_02::ypos=480 sink_00::alpha=1.0 sink_01::alpha=1.0 sink_02::alpha=1.0 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink \
               v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, width=1600, height=1200, framerate=25/1 ! alpha alpha=1.0 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-480  ! mix. \
               v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw, width=800,  height=480,  framerate=25/1 ! alpha alpha=1.0 ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-00  ! mix. -e
```

You need to use a `videobox` element for each videocapture (in this case I used `v4l2src` however you can use other sources like `filesrc ! decodebin` or a network source as well) pipe and combine them in a `videomixer` element.

In my case I used one video on the left and two videos on the right but you can adjust `left` and `top` parameters of `videobox` and  `sink_0x::xpos' and 'sink_0x::ypos` elements of the `videomixer` element.

Remember to add `alpha` to each channel or your videos will be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

So this depends very much on how and what you want to do. For example, this can be be as simple GUI application that presents 4 videos on 4 different surfaces and the GUI is responsible for the layout.

If you really want to create a new single image that contains these 4 video streams then `videomixer` sounds the way to go. See here for some example:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videomixer.html

Comment: I want it as 1 image/video

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example of doing it like the picture in my question?

Comment: Check the last example. I guess you need to scale videos to your wanted sizes and feed all to the videomixer. Via the pad options xpos and ypos you can set positional offsets. The smaller ones will probably take an posx of the width of the big one..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch can you please suggest me which UI framework can help with creating 4 video displays and updating the displays in real time with respective video feed input? (Open source framework)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to mix running streams into a single one

```
/usr/local/bin/gst-launch-1.0 -vv -e videomixer name=mix background=2 \
        sink_0::alpha=1.0 \
        sink_0::ypos=0 \
        sink_0::xpos=0 \
        sink_1::alpha=1.0 \
        sink_1::ypos=80 \
        sink_1::xpos=40 \
        sink_2::alpha=1.0 \
        sink_2::ypos=80 \
        sink_2::xpos=410 \
        sink_3::alpha=1.0 \
        sink_3::ypos=80 \
        sink_3::xpos=780 \
        sink_0::zorder=1 \
        sink_1::zorder=3 \
        sink_2::zorder=3 \
        sink_3::zorder=4 \
        ! clockoverlay auto-resize=false draw-shadow=false draw-outline=false halignment=left valignment=top \
        ! timeoverlay auto-resize=false draw-shadow=false draw-outline=false halignment=left valignment=bottom \
        ! queue \
            ! nvh264enc preset=1 bitrate=1500 rc-mode=2 gop-size=10 \
            ! h264parse config-interval=-1 \
            ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay pt=33 \
            ! udpsink host=239.255.42.61 port=5004 multicast-iface=10g-1 ttl=4 ttl-mc=4 \
        multifilesrc location=/IMG/logo.jpg caps="image/jpeg,framerate=1/1" \
            ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
                ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 \
            ! mix.sink_0 \
        udpsrc multicast-group=239.255.42.60 address=239.255.42.60 port=5004 multicast-iface=eth0 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP2T,payload=(int)33" \
                ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 \
            ! avdec_h264 skip-frame=1 output-corrupt=false ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
            ! video/x-raw,width=360,height=240 \
                ! mix.sink_1 \
        udpsrc multicast-group=239.255.42.57 address=239.255.42.57 port=5004 multicast-iface=eth0 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP2T,payload=(int)33" \
                ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 \
            ! avdec_h264 skip-frame=1 output-corrupt=false ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
            ! video/x-raw,width=360,height=240 \
            ! mix.sink_2 \
        udpsrc multicast-group=239.255.42.62 address=239.255.42.62 port=5004 multicast-iface=eth0 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP2T,payload=(int)33" \
                ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 \
            ! avdec_h264 skip-frame=1 output-corrupt=false ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
            ! video/x-raw,width=360,height=240 \
            ! mix.sink_3 \
```